# Access 2007 Left join and nulls

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I ran the following simple query that looks like the example below:
(Briefly; one order has from 1 to N items and the foreign key is order_id in table items)

```
SELECT orders.*, items.*
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN
items ON orders.id= items.order_id
```

This shows something like:

```
order.id    item.id
   1           34
   1           22
   1           90
   2           44
   2           19
   2           21
   2           22
```

I want an output like:

```
order.id    item.id
   1           34
               22
               90
   2           44
               19
               21
               22
```

How to achieve that on Access 2007 ?

Thank you in advance,
Miloud B.

Comment: 1) Why do you want to do this? 2) What is the logic that dictates the order of `item.id`? Can it be arbitrary? i.e. could 1 be paired with `22` not `34`?

Comment: The item's id doesn't matter at all, it's just a number I show up. I want to do that to provide the user with a more readable output. Thx

Comment: What you want to do is change the display in the user interface, not the sql query. Are you displaying the results on a form or report? You cannot (should not) do this in the query itself.

Comment: If you want to "provide the user with a more readable output" use reports ! There's a control property to hide repeated values in there. A query is a data tool, not a presentation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this would be a self join with an aggregate. It will be easier/better handled in your application.

```
SELECT
         IIF( i2.id = MIN(i.id), i.order_id, NULL) AS order_id,
         i2.id AS item_id
FROM     items i
         INNER JOIN orders o
         ON       o.id= i.order_id
         LEFT JOIN items i2
         ON       i2.order_id=i.order_id
GROUP BY i.order_id
ORDER BY i.order_id,
         i2.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip ! Brilliant trick ;). @Remou: Case has to become IIF and then it works perfectly !